# Авторизация в yii2

Tags: php, yii2, авторизация

у меня вот такая задача. При регистрации должен выдавать выдавать bearer-токен. Я не понимаю как его генерировать. И потом как его использовать.
Задание звучит так :
Авторизация пользователя при использовании административных функциональных возможностей будет проверяться через bearer-token авторизацию. Т.е. к каждому такому запросу в headers будет дописываться bearer-token:
Authorization: Bearerxxxxxxxx

Comment: У вас rest приложение? После регистрации, возвращайте access_token пользователя, и при отправке запросов добавьте заголовок `Authorization` со значением `Bearer ваш_токен`

Comment: ЕМНИП в yii2 есть встроенная авторизация по bearer-токен, но хелперов на генерацию - нету. Так, что всё самому. Но там просто.